# Cross-file PHP variables?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of database addresses and other random long strings that I must input into functions again and again all over my site. Is there a way to make a ton of permanent, global variables in PHP that will be valid on any file on the current PHP installation?

Or should I just make a vars.php with all of the variables defined, and always include that file?

Comment: You probably mean global constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your file with the settings you need. Something like this:

```
<?php
    // My file name might be config.php
    $config = array(
        'db.connection' => 'localhost:3306'
        // etc...
    );
?>
```

Then include it into each page/file that needs it.

```
<?php
    require("path-to/config.php");

    // Other stuff this file does/needs
?>
```

Comment: i'd use require_once("file.php") :)

Comment: +1 except I agree with mister koz, you should use `require_once`

Comment: @mister, @andrew: I don't `require_once` unless I'm importing a class. The overhead is unnecessary given this instance because the values are, what should be, unalterable config values. Importing agian will not hurt anything.

Comment: Unless it is a file of constants, classes, functions, or anything else that kills when declared multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, well, both! Use prepend.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend/

Comment: If at all possible, it would be best to summarize the technique in some code within your answer.

Comment: Ick, please stay away form INI settings like this. Just use `require` or `include` on each file that needs it.

Comment: I see no reason to stay away from auto_prepend_file. It's used often for sessions or the exact purpose that the OP asked for. I don't personally use it, but I can't see a reason why using require() or include() repeatedly is better practice. BTW, OP, auto_prepend_file calls things like require() and not include() which means the script will crash if the file cannot be found.

Comment: because it is explict and easy to find/read from the code. Using INI settings means that it would be necessary to read/find server configuration in addition to code.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use $GLOBALS variable, which also contains other superglobals like $_GET, $_POST etc. Of course that means you should still always include file where you define your own custom variable.

The good thing when using $GLOBALS is you can use it in all scopes, and at least imho you can use it as a sort of a namespacing technique.

For example if you use

```
$settings = array('host' => 'localhost');
    function connect() {
        global $settings;
    }
```

there's a possibility that you unintentionally override $setting variable at some point. When using $GLOBALS, I think this kind of scenario is not so likely to happen.

```
$GLOBALS['_SETTINGS'] = array(... => ...);
    function connect() {
       $settings = $GLOBALS['_SETTINGS'];
    }
```

Another solution would be using your own custom class, where you store your settings in a static array. Again, this requiers including file, where you define the class, but your data will be avialable within all scopes and cannot be acidently overriden.

Example:

```
class MySettings {

    private static $settings = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root'
    );

    public static get($key) {
        return self::$settings[$key];
    }

}

function connect() {
    $host = MySettings::get('host');
    ...
}
```

Not saying it's the best way for doing this, but surely one way for accomplishing your goal.